# C# WebForm - Add averages of student marks, print result in the web form, then store it in the database

Tags: c#

```
protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int StudentAdmissionNo  = Convert.ToInt32(txtAdmissionNo.Text);
      string StudentName = txtStudentName.Text;
      DateTime DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
      string Gender = txtGender.Text;
      string Standard = txtstandard.Text;
      string Section = txtSection.Text;
      int Telugu = Convert.ToInt32(txtTelugu.Text);
      int English = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnglish.Text);
      int Mathematics = Convert.ToInt32(txtMathematics.Text);
      //int Total = Convert.ToInt32(lblTot.Text);
      //double Average = Convert.ToDouble(lblAve.Text);
      string Result = lblRes.Text;

      lblTot.Text = (txtTelugu.Text + txtEnglish.Text + txtMathematics.Text); # Total in coming if i enter the 45 65 65 = its coming 456565 like i did wrong?

      lblAve.Text = ((lblTot.Text) / 3.00); //This also gives an error
}
```

In this code I have an error coming from `lblTot =` to add marks and it coming like same to printing that numbers what I entered and average also not working.

Comment: That's english or keyword list ? Bingo.

Comment: Please focus on improving the quality of the above code block. Looks very unorganized and prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the Text. When you use + with text/string it acts as a concatenation operator.

You need to convert text to Integer for arithmatic operations first.

Use **Convert.ToInt32(input);**

Replacing your code with the below lines should fix it.

```
lblTot.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtTelugu.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtEnglish.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtMathematics.Text)).ToString();

lblAve.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(lblTot.Text)) / 3.00).ToString();
```

### Update

I just noticed that you have already assigned the required values to integers here:

```
  int Telugu = Convert.ToInt32(txtTelugu.Text);
  int English = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnglish.Text);
  int Mathematics = Convert.ToInt32(txtMathematics.Text);
```

Which is correct, you just needed to add these variables, like:

```
int total = Telugu + English + Mathematics;
lblTot.Text = total.ToString();
```

And then, for average just use the `total` variable that we just assigned the value to:

```
lblAve.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(total / 3.00)); // convert the average to double as you may get values with decimal point. And then convert it back to string in order to assign it to a Label control.
```

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption of what you're trying to do is correct your code should look like this.

```
decimal total = Teluga + English + Mathematics;
decimal average = (Teluga + English + Mathematics) / 3.00;
lblTot.Text = total.ToString();
lblAve.Text = average.ToString();
```

You are trying to use strings to perform mathematical operations and that won't work.

Also, typically

```
int x = Int32.TryParse(txtEnglish.Text)
```

is a better way to turn string into integers

Answer (score 0):

The root of both your problems is that a textbox.Text property is a `string`.

In your first problem, you are concatenating strings, which is why it's giving you you 456565.

In your second problem, you are trying to perform arithmetic on a string and a number.

Cast your strings as numbers by declaring an `Int32` variable placeholder and using the TryParse method on your `string`, like so:

```
Int32 txtTeluguResult;
Int32.TryParse(txtTelugu.Text, txtTeluguResult);
```

Also note that TryParse will put 0 in for your result variable if it cannot successfully parse the text input. You may wish to use `Convert.ToInt32()` instead, which throws a FormatException if it fails, depending on what behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
lblTot.Text = (txtTelugu.Text + txtEnglish.Text + txtMathematics.Text); # Total in coming if i enter the 45 65 65 = its coming 456565 like i did wrong?

lblAve.Text = ((lblTot.Text) / 3.00); this also giving error?
```

you are using string variables not int or real or decimal

do something like

```
lblTot.Text = (((int)txtTelugu.Text + (int)txtEnglish.Text + (int)txtMathematics.Text)).ToString();    
lblAve.Text = (((int)(lblTot.Text) / 3.00)).ToString(); this also giving error?
```